# A.R Drone Project

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, opencv, ar.drone

I wanted to ask abut potential project idea using `node.js` and `opencv`. I want to use the node.js code shown below and somehow link it to opencv for object recognition. Like following a straight path for a gutter from one end to the other. Typically gutters are white and I feel like that color is hard to detect and follow. I'm not too sure. I am new to opencv and node.js and was wondering if I get any feedback or some sample code related to my project. Are there other ways to go about this project?

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var client  = arDrone.createClient();

client.takeoff();

client
      .after(2000, function() {
        this.up(1);
      })
      .after(5000, function() {
        this.front(1.0);
      })
      .after(2000, function() {
        this.clockwise(0.5);
      })
      .after(5000, function() {
        this.back(0.8);
      })
      .after(2000, function() {
        this.land();
      });
```

Comment: I think using `node.js` with OpenCV is a bad idea. Why not use one of the languages which wraps OpenCVs C++ library nicely?

Comment: I don't know what codes control the drone in C++

Comment: Is this library good for windows computers or just Linux. I installed opencv, are all C++ libraries there already

Comment: OpenCV is by default, all in C++. You can use different languages, such as Python or Android (Java), to essentially make a wrapper around the C++ version so you can interact with it through those languages. After some poking around, I found a wrapper for `node.js`. https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv    Keep in  mind that this binding doesn't support OpenCV 3 yet

Comment: So can I link this code to follow a straight line or should just create an image on the gutter of a straight line or something like that

Comment: You have to realize, either way is the same principle. Take an image of what is below the drone, process the image to make sure the white line is underneath the drone by a certain amount. The only difference is when you do it live, you take multiple pictures at a faster frequency, or in other words a video.

Comment: I see. With streaming, I have tried many things with improving latency. Using ffplay, ffmpeg, and some other sources online. Is there a way to improve that. Because I feel like the delay will mess up the code. I posted this question earlier:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062700/faster-real-time-a-r-drone-video-streaming

Comment: You can try to just read an image every second to see if that helps with latency. Adjust the course of the drone every second instead of constantly adjusting the direction, because it's only a straight line and the course isn't going to change drastically every millisecond.

Comment: Do you know of any streaming techniques, codes like that?

Comment: You can try to just take a picture using OpenCVs `VideoCapture()` method for now. Eventually you can advance your code to take pictures from a video stream.